# Foundation.framework is belong to CoreService layer or CocoaTouch Layer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa, core-services

The Cocoa (Touch) Document [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Cocoa.html) say:

```
Cocoa Touch, which includes Foundation and UIKit frameworks, is used for developing applications that run on iOS.
```

But the Core Services Layer Document [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html) say:

```
The Core Services layer contains fundamental system services for apps. Key among these services are the Core Foundation and Foundation frameworks, which define the basic types that all apps use. This layer also contains individual technologies to support features such as location, iCloud, social media, and networking."
```

So which layer of Foundation.framework is belong to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocoa (Touch) is the all-encompassing umbrella for the layer stack.  The Cocoa (Touch) Application Layer is a specific layer within that stack and is sometimes referred to as simply the Application layer.

The `Core Foundation` framework and the `Foundation` framework are both part of the `Core Services` layer.

As you mentioned, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html) is the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html) on the subject.